# Should this folder called Data be indexed?

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

In the indexing options of Windows 7 there is a folder called `Data` which is excluded from indexing for the `C:\` drive by default.

[image: Data Folder on drive C]
Can someone confirm this, please? I was not able to locate that folder on my drive, nor include it in the search index.

The difference in number of indexed files is unsatisfying: windows-7 native indexing service:377703 files on six drives; third party desktop search indexing service:698654 files on the same number of drives.

Files in UA Control seem not being indexed without proper priviledges. How can this be circumvented?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a little bit late, but for all out there with the same problem. The directory is:

```
%SYSTEMDRIVE%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data
```

By default it is excluded. This is the index folder where the index files are stored and it contains around 60 files. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about *AppData*, perhaps?  It's the only excluded folder included by default in my almost fresh installation of Windows 7:

[image: Indexing Options]

The `AppData` folder is where Windows and programs store their data files.  For instance, your web browser might store its bookmarks and history data in this folder.  By default, the folder is hidden from view, but it resides in your profile folder, which generally appears in Windows with your name on it.  This directory is not indexed by default because it often contains very large data files that would increase the size of your search index and slow down searching tremendously.

To access the *AppData* folder, just type this into the Windows Explorer address bar and press Enter:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData
```

You can also enable hidden file and folder display in the *Folder Options* control panel.  Be careful though, removing or modifying files in this directory could cause Windows and/or your applications to malfunction or stop working altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem. It seems to me that *any* folder with "data" as part of it's name is excluded. I can't find a way to prevent this folder (e.g. C:\Data) from being excluded. Hence I renamed the folder. Sigh.